# FlexBox Layout Android. How to delete vertical gaps between views?

Tags: flexbox

I'm generating Views inside FlexBox layout by pressing the Start button. As you can see every item on even line has random size. It works almost as it supposed to be but there is a problem, I need to get rid of vertical gaps between two vertically adjacent views. I've tried all properties of Flex Box Layout but didn't find one that can help to solve my problem. I will be happy if you help me to solve this problem.

[image]

Comment: Ru using this lib? https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Comment: It's exactly what I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem. If you have the same task you should use Relative Layout and its' flags inside your android code. It'll give you all control under the positions of Views. If it will be necessary I can expand this answer to provide more detail.